# show user location on a map and stop location

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapkit, core-location

Here is my goal:
I have to show the user location with his address on a map every time he open the view that has the MapView and then stop location to save battery. So far i can do it, but if the user moves to another area and enter the view (after leave it) the location does not change.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    if(!self.locationManager){
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    self.locationManager = nil;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion =
    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(newLocation.coordinate, 2000, 2000);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [mapView setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];

    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

    MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc]
                                   initWithCoordinate:newLocation.coordinate];
    geocoder.delegate = self;
    [geocoder start];    
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {

    MapLocation *annotation = [[MapLocation alloc] init];
    annotation.streetAddress = placemark.thoroughfare;
    annotation.city = placemark.locality;
    annotation.state = placemark.administrativeArea;
    annotation.zip = placemark.postalCode;
    annotation.coordinate = geocoder.coordinate;

    [mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

    geocoder.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)openCallout:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    [mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {
    static NSString *placemarkIdentifier = @"Map Location Identifier";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapLocation class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[theMapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:placemarkIdentifier];
        if (annotationView == nil)  {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:placemarkIdentifier];
        }
        else{
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }
        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"rescue"];
        [self performSelector:@selector(openCallout:) withObject:annotation afterDelay:0.5];

        return annotationView;

    }
    return nil;
}
```

I have a CLLocationManager on another view that get user location without a map (here the location is working just fine). If a start the location on that view and go back to the view with the map it's is updated. Why that?

Any ideias?

Comment: `locationManager` is created in `viewDidAppear` but its `delegate` is set in `viewDidLoad` (which would happen before `viewDidAppear`).  How is `locationManager` not `nil` on load?  Anyway, a quick fix might be to also set the delegate and desiredAccuracy after creating it in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)loadView {
    MKMapView *mv = [[MKMapView alloc]init];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    mv.delegate=self;
}
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES];
    mapView.showsUserLocation=NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well to display it on the map

```
MKMapView *mv = [[MKMapView alloc]init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D c = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude);
[mv setCenterCoordinate:c animated:YES];
```

and to stop updating

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
```